# AJAX (jQuery) Response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Suppose all forms in your application has this structure:

```
<div id="result_messages"></div>
<form action="/action">
<!-- all the form -->
</form>
```

A submit button for this form looks like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$.post( '/action', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
   $('#result_messages').html( data );      // At this point the 'data' is an standard HTML with a message
});" />
```

BUT, But not always the response is a message... how to detect when data is a message or not??????:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$.post( '/action', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
   if (isMessage( data ))
       $('#result_messages').html( data );      
   else
        doActionWith( data );
});" />
```

Using JSON maybe a solution:

```
{ response_type : 'message', data: 'all_data_here' }

{ response_type : 'nomessage', data: 'all_data_here' }
```

Other solution is to put a special STRING at the begin of data:

```
<!--message--><ul><li>form was processed</li></ul>
```

Have you other ideas? what do you think about this solutions?

Comment: What do you mean «not always is a message»? What is it, the other times?

Answer (score 2):

> what do you think about this solutions?
>
> `<input type="button" onclick="$.post( "/action", $(form).serialize(), function (data) {`

1. That will fall over. The quote before `/action` will terminate the onclick attribute value
2. Inline JS is nasty. Bind your event handlers from external scripts.
3. If JS is not available, this won't work. Write a form that works (with a regular submit button) and then progressively enhance with JS.
4. `form` is undefined, that should be `this.form`
5. `/action` is repeating yourself. Write more reusable code: `this.form.action`

> Using JSON maybe a solution

Yes. Use a structured data format instead of a blob of code to shove into the page.

Comment: all my codes for this questions are totally illustrative... this helps you understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

What are the options, other than simple html output? json?

If so, you can send an object back and check it in the callback.